# Retrieving data from a secure website using php curl with username and password

Tags: php

I am new in curl,i want to retrieve website data through curl using userid and password in php.But i don't know how to do that. If anyone know please let me know.

Comment: If you expect an answer, you need to be more specific. What kind of data? What format is it in? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add your code?

Comment: Hey  Martynasma, i try lot and able to login now but still not able to see other pages data because of session.So can you help me how to preserve session for all other pages through curl?